# Issue with CSS3 background gradient between Chrome & Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, css, safari

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(92,92,92,0.95) 0%,rgba(92,92,92,0.65) 45%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 45%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 47%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 47%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(92,92,92,0.95) 0%,rgba(92,92,92,0.65) 45%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 45%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 47%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 47%);
```

These two lines are identical, but produce different results. You can see what's on production here (http://www.eprize.com/what-we-do/#mobile). In Chrome one shows two 45 degree gray vertical stripes whereas in Firefox the one bleeds over the whole image rather than being a second vertical stripe.

I've spent some time Googling for this but have only found results for CSS3 generators, which is not what I want. Any help on getting Firefox to look like how this looks in Safari & Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Firefox's insistance on a start and end point for all color stops. The final and 5th color stop was supposed to make the rest of the gradient transparent, but did not. Here is the fix.

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.95) 0%, rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.65) 45%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 45%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 47%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 47%), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
```